# How to limit connections per second and IP on apache2?

Tags: apache2, ddos

Hi! I have been having recurrent problems on my apache2, some group of people is bombarding my server with HTTP petitions to all my forms, everything collapses and my service is interrupted.

How can I limit the amount of petitions per seconds to my users?
Or which is the usual way to address this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we do server and url level protection using mod_qos

It wasn't super easy to understand or install BUT it sure is powerful.

read some of the sample/examples on the page, you will find one that fits your problem

http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/

Comment: I thought so too, but then I found this in the apache error log: `[notice] mod_qos(009): loaded MPM is 'Prefork' but mod_qos should be used with MPM 'Worker' only.`. Then I learned that MPM 'Worker' in Apache 2.2 is discouraged in the php manual: `Why shouldn't I use Apache2 with a threaded MPM in a production environment?` `http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache2` :(